# Cannot able use Multiple rule in mod_rewrie

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need used use it

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^9090$

RewriteRule ^vendor/([0-9]+).html$ 
productcategory.iface?Operation=category&catid=$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^vendor/([0-9]+)([0-9]+).html$
productcategory.iface?Operation=product&prodid=$2

RewriteRule ^vendor/([0-9]+)([0-9]+)([0-9]+).html$
productcategory.iface?Operation=vendet&prodid=$2&venid=$3

But I Used this rule i found Error on 500 that is misconfiguration error

Comment: give us some examples of the urls you expect to re-write from please

Comment: Do you need this condition RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} to be applied to the first rule only? If you need it to affect all rules, you need to repeat it before each of them. And regarding your problem, can you see something in Apache logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line breaks inside the directives are not allowed. So try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^9090$
RewriteRule ^vendor/([0-9]+)\.html$ productcategory.iface?Operation=category&catid=$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^vendor/([0-9]+)\([0-9]+)\.html$ productcategory.iface?Operation=product&prodid=$2
RewriteRule ^vendor/([0-9]+)\([0-9]+)\([0-9]+)\.html$ productcategory.iface?Operation=vendet&amp;prodid=$2&amp;venid=$3
```